# Did Snoke have any other apprentices before Kylo Ren?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi

We know that Kylo Ren is Supreme Leader Snoke's apprentice, but recently I was wondering: **Did Snoke have any other apprentices before Kylo Ren?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Snoke has had at least one other, and potentially several other apprentices over the years.

The Star Wars Insider [Last Jedi: Special Collector's edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_The_Last_Jedi_-_The_Official_Collector%27s_Edition) contains the following cryptic note

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>"*Force sensitive, and highly attuned to the dark tide but not a Sith,
> Snoke has trained Kylo Ren and least one other apprentice.*"</sup></sub>

And the [Visual Dictionary for The Force Awakens](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary) states that Kylo Ren is the most gifted of (presumably) several apprentices.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>"*Kylo Ren is the most gifted apprentice of Supreme Leader Snoke, a mysterious figure steeped in dark side knowledge who commands the First Order from a distance.*"</sup></sub>

Comment: I knew I'd seen it somewhere before but you beat me to it...

Comment: Snoke trained Plageius: CONFIRMED!

Answer (score 0):

The Rise of Skywalker has now shed new light on Snokes backstory.

> Snoke is not a real being but is in fact a facet of the emperor Palpatine, it is not yet understood exactly how Palpatine controlled the being that is Snoke but it is strongly suggested that Snoke is in fact a clone and acted as either the puppet for, or was controlled by Palpatine. Therefore strictly speaking yes there where other apprentices, the most famous being Darth Vader.